# Qt and Python, where to configure signals and slots

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

Howdo,
 I've just started getting into Python and QT. I have a very simplistic question. I wanted to create a Qt window to display the output and accept input from a program that I am attempting.

My question is, in Qt Designer I have made said window, but I'm not sure if I have to set the signals and slots in designer or in python. For the output I had used a QtextBroswer widget and a QPlainTextEdit for the input. Are those the correct choices for my uses.

Also do I need to muck about with setting slots and signals in Designer, or no?

Any and all help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: PyQt or PySide? Not that it matters much (mainly for tagging), their syntaxes and semantics are very similar.

Comment: I have both installed. though i was going to go with PyQt4.

Comment: The best place for your signal/slot definitions is within the `__init__()` of your widgets. Usually the QMainWindow. Don't make any edits to the python file that is converted from your Ui. Just import it, and use it to `setupUi()` your main window

Answer (score 2):

Set the signals and slots in Python. When you export the ui to Python using `pyuic4` or `pyside-uic`, the signals and slots are set using python anyways.

Comment: Thank you much jordoex for the speedy response. I have to admit That I am finding the whole Qt thing a bit overwhelming. So are the widgets I had chosen, the right ones.

Comment: @kenbrockman: This does answer the question so you should accept the answer. But just to add... For PyQt development, use the Designer strictly for visual layout. The extra stuff in there is handy for the C++ users, but really its much easier to do everything in python. The Ui file should be just your view and no logic.

Comment: Thank you jdl, for your somewhat  more detailed answer.. I did accept the answer. I've just hooked up with this site and as such, was a tad slow to realize i was to accept the answers. Mea Culpa.